# Get value from span tag and deduct % from it (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

On the product page the price is displayed inside two span tag:

```
<div class="price-container">
    <span class="price-regular">
        <span class="price">$10.00</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

What I want to do is deduct 15% from the regular price and display the deducted amount below it. How can I accomplish this as the price field is dynamic and the value also contains `$` sign before it? I need to do the calculation using JavaScript but I am still learning it.

Comment: Which part exactly do you not know how to do? Getting the span contents, removing the $, deducing the 15%, or something else?

Comment: What does the rest of your HTML look like? How can anyone know how you want to display it? Are there multiple such `span` elements on the page? How do you want the outputted price to be formatted? What other code do you currently have? Your question is severely lacking in detail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; please read our [ask] page to improve your question.  Great questions get faster, better answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the adjusted price by getting the current price, then doing the math to make the adjustment.  Finally add the discounted price to the HTML DOM.

**HTML**

```
<span class="price">$10.00</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//build an array with all the prices
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('price');

//set the discount
var discount = .15;

//loop over all the prices
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  //get the price
    var price = spans[i].innerHTML;

  //remove the dollar sign
  price = price.replace('$','');
  //convert the price to a float
  price = parseFloat(price);
  //apply the discount, and use toFixed(2) for ensure we keep 2 decimal places
  var discountedPrice = (price * (1-discount)).toFixed(2);

  //update the HTML by adding the discounted price below the original
  spans[i].innerHTML = '<s>'+spans[i].innerHTML + '</s><br />$' + discountedPrice;

}
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4zjkv68/2/

Hope that helps!